# HTML5 Audio. Replacing Element still the same audio file (cached) how to solve?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, html5-audio

I am using the HTML5 Audio element inside my HTML file.

Trying many methods,I just cannot manage to replace the audio file via AJAX, it still returns the same audiofile.

```
<div id="audiodiv">
   <audio id="audioelement">
    <source src="test.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
   </audio>
</div>
```

So I record a new file called test.ogg which overwrites the old one.
I tried using jQuery and using`$("#audiodiv").html('')`
and re-rendering this part. Then fetching the element via `document.getElementbyID` and then using the `.play() function` .

It returns the same old test.ogg,which was already overwritten by the new one.

So I tried to delete the cache, still the same problem.

The only way this works is deleting the cache and closing the browser and calling the page again...

How can I solve this?

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: You can also add a cache busting param in the audio src url like `var src = "test.ogg?cache-buster=" + new Date().getTime()`

Comment: not working as i use similar method on my js file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not going to change the name of the file but keep updating it then you need to add immediate `Expires` HTTP headers to the response on the server side.  Exactly how you do this depends on which server you're using.  Common ones include [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) and [IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661%28WS.10%29.aspx).

However, it would be easier, and also [better practice](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires), to let the browser cache the audio and just give each new file a different name.

Comment: Thanks for answering this. I will take a closer look into HTTP Headers.

Comment: @zer02 I fixed the issue simply by passing a timestamp as querystring parameter. ex: `var param = new Date().getTime();  src = src + "?cb=" + param;  audio.load(src); audio.play(); ` thanks to the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25823431/1201322

Comment: @Ravimallya to me this trick doesn't work ...on a streaming file ... when I stop and replay, it starts playing exactly from the point in which I stopped, instead of refreshing the buffer, in order to get the point really streamed by the station

Answer (score 4):

I used the same file server side using a JS no cache trick like this:

```
var audioPlayer =  $('<audio src="/' + mp3FileName + '?noCache=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) + '" type="audio/mpeg" autoplay controls></audio>');
```

Setting the Expire, Last-Modified, and Cache-control header didn't work for me, but adding a random string of numbers to the src as a GET variable did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest and easiest solution is to change the name of the file. This will resolve the issue. Otherwise go with robertc's solution. Personally I would just change the filename.

Answer (score 0):

IF you place the `<audio>` tag in an `<iframe>`

THEN refresh the `<iframe>` with a 5 second delay during the event where you upload your new sound file.  It might output your new sound file.

```
$('#UploadNewSoundButton').click(function(){
       //insert code that uploads new sound file 

       setTimeout(function(){
            window.frames['iframeWithAudio'].location.reload();
        },5000)   
 })
```

maybe???  I'm new here.