# How to force the HTML5 Audio tag to reload a (changing) file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bit of code in javascript that generates a wav file and then attaches it to a button so it can be played:

```
function makeWav(){        
            $.get(("../testsound/getsound.pl?text="+document.myform.outputtext.value));
setTimeout(callback, 500);
            return false;
        }
function callback() {
var audio = new Audio('http://www.joereddington.com/testsound/hope.wav');
audio.load();
audio.play();
           //     $("#player").html("<embed src=http://www.joereddington.com/testsound/hope.wav autostart=true  >");
        }
```

Obviously the hope.wav file changes very regularly.  But my problem is that only the *first* .wav to be generated is played unless I completely reload the site each time.  How do I make the (presumably) callback function go and get a new version of the .wav rather than the cache?

EDIT: Works fine on the iPad - I'm having this problem in firefox.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can't directly control the caching from within your JavaScript. Retrieving files is the responsibility of the browser, which is why you're getting different results on different browsers.

When a web server sends a file to the browser, it also sends some headers with extra details about that file. One of them is [the `Cache-Control` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9), which tells the browser if the file is cacheable. Sending a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header *should* stop browsers caching the file, and make subsequent requests retrieve the file from your server.

On Apache, you can use [an `.htaccess` file or a `<Directory>` rule in your server configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) to change the caching for files in the `/testsound` directory. Put the following in `/testsound/.htaccess`:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control no-cache
</ifModule>
```

---

Another technique is to include a "cache-busting" parameter in your request. Your web server is serving a static file - but your web browser *doesn't know that*. For all it knows, a request for `/testsound/hope.wav?cb=foo` could return a completely different file to a request for `/testsound/hope.wav?cb=bar`. Thus, if you include an always-changing parameter in your web request, the browser won't find it in its cache and it will retrieve the new file. A timestamp is a good choice:

```
function callback() {
  var url = "http://www.joereddington.com/testsound/hope.wav?cb=" + new Date().getTime();
  var audio = new Audio(url);
  audio.load();
  audio.play();        
}
```

Comment: I'm upvoting because I already learned sensible things from your answer.  Will try and come back to accept... :)

Comment: 30 seconds later.  Everything is gravy.  Well done. (I used the second suggestion because it avoids having to have yet another carefully configured file.)

Comment: chrome data saver somehow bypasses this

Answer (score 10):

For those trying to change the `src` attribute of a source element, I found [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element:the-source-element-12) spec note .

> Dynamically modifying a source element and its attribute when the element is
> already inserted in a video or audio element will have no effect. To
> change what is playing, just use the src attribute on the media
> element directly

So lets say you have:

```
<audio>
    <source src='./first-src'/>
</audio>
```

To modify the src:

```
<audio src='./second-src'/>
    <source src='./first-src'/>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Speech()
{
     var fileName = new Date().getTime();

     $.ajax({
         url: Host + "api/speech",
         data: {
             'text': $("input[id='searchBox']").val(),
             'language': $("input[id='languageChoice']:checked").val(),
             'fileName': fileName
         },
         dataType: "json",
         type: "Get",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function () {
             var audioUrl = Host + '/Assets/Audio/' + fileName + '.mp3';
             var audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
             audio.load();
             audio.play();
         }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3 it helped me to use `preload="none"` and to change the fileURL with an `?[Date.now()]` suffix, every time there is an update in the audio file (change shown with loading prop).

It seems the `?[date12233333]` suffix tricks browsers cache, and makes it load the audio file again.

```
// VUE 3 example
<template>
  <div v-if="!src || loading">
    ... loading
  </div>
  <audio v-else controls preload="none" :src="src" type="audio/mpeg" />
</template>
<script>
import {ref, watch} from "vue";

export default {
  name: "Audio",
  props: {
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
    src: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    setup(props) {
      const srcUpdated = ref(null)
      watch(() => props.loading, () => {
        srcUpdated.value = props.src + "?" + Date.now();
      })
      return {
        srcUpdated
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```