# Javascript function plays wrong audio file

Tags: javascript, function, audio, playback

I'm having trouble with this javascript function

```
function playaudio(p){                                                          
    sound.pause();
    $("#audiovoix")[0].currentTime = 0;
    $("#audiovoix").attr("src", "fiches_visite/"+id+"/audio/"+p+"_FR.mp3");
    console.log("fiches_visite/"+id+"/audio/"+p+"_FR.mp3");
    sound.load();
    sound.play();
    sound.onerror = function() {
        console.log("fichier introuvable");
        itvl = setTimeout(function() { 
        $('#slider_suivant').trigger('click'); }, tempo);
    };                                      
}
```

This function is called within a picture slider, and p is an identifier int. It changes the audio tag src, plays it, or trigger a click if an error is returned (i don't use ajax to check if file exists on purpose).

Problem is, if the file does not actually exists, it fetches another file in the folder and plays it. It should just return an error but it does not... Why an other file i didn't ask for is played ? How to avoid this ?

My audio folder is something like : 1_FR.mp3, 3_FR.mp3, etc.

Thanks

Comment: What does your console.log say when it plays a wrong file?

Comment: The right file is given in the console.log

Comment: You said the file plays even if one doesn't exist. What file plays when the clicked file doesn't exist? Post the output of the console when it is wrong.

Comment: For example, i have only one file in my folder : 0_FR.mp3. When i run the function, p = 1, it outputs "fiches_visite/2/audio/1_FR.mp3" which does not exist, and "fiches_visite/2/audio/0_FR.mp3" is played instead.

Comment: Are you sure got the correct path? Because having a variable here: `"fiches_visite/"+id+"/audio/` at `+id+` means you are juggling multiple directories, correct?

Comment: yes, path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a cache problem, i finally found the solution on this thread [HTML5 Audio. Replacing Element still the same audio file (cached) how to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041206/html5-audio-replacing-element-still-the-same-audio-file-cached-how-to-solve)

In my code i just added an argument after the audio filename and it solved the problem

```
$("#audiovoix").attr("src", "fiches_visite/"+id+"/audio/"+p+"_FR.mp3?cache-buster=" + new Date().getTime());
```